# Why would you place a resistor in series before AND after a diode (see simple circuit)?

Tags: diodes, current-limiting, ballast

For an assignment we had to first simulate a circuit (first with a Schottky then with a rectifying diode) in LTSpice and then do measurements on an actual circuit before answering a few questions. Below are the schemes of the simulated and measured circuits:

[image]
[image]

To the questions
**"How is the current limited?"**

That seems pretty clear, Rg is acts as a ballast resistor to limit the current across the diode

**"What is the purpose of R2?"**

With this one I´m having troube... Rg ist already acting as a current limiter. I've read that it does not really matter whether you place your resistor before of after the diode, so I don't know why you whould do both... Also I suspect the purpose of Rg and R2 is different because R1 is noticeably larger in value than R2.

Am I missing some important detail?

Comment: I want to make sure that I follow the context. It appears that you are using an AC source and setting the oscilloscope into X-Y mode to observe the resulting trace? Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schematic suggests that you are being asked to apply an oscilloscope set into X-Y mode (one of the channels will have a large **X** written near it, for example.) This is where one of the input channels on your scope replaces the internal time-base section. (It's interesting to [see a comparison of X-Y mode usage with analog vs digital scopes](https://youtu.be/1tTeXPmbxW0).)

If you are using an oscilloscope set into X-Y mode and assuming you've got the triggering working well enough, then you should observe a repeated curve that starts low (on the **y**-axis) at the left and shows a rising exponential curve of sorts heading towards the right side of the scope.

Rather than go to all the trouble of building it and taking a photo, I'll cheat a little and use LTspice in X-Y mode to show you what I mean using two different diodes:

[image]

I've overlapped two different diode curves onto one screen. You won't be able to do that with your setup. But LTspice lets me switch diodes quickly, so I can do it with that software program.

The reason for the \$1\:\Omega\$ resistor is that it makes it very easy to estimate the current in the diode for any voltage across it (because you just divide by 1.)

In case it matters, you can see how I approximated your schematic in LTspice:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the more complete answer, nice!

Comment: @JohnD When I read the schematic, the **X** and **Y** were sufficient to force me to look at the power source. Yup, it was AC! (Otherwise, what's the point?) Then the 1 Ohm resistor was obvious. That was the sequence for me. Then I saw your answer and felt you may have focused more narrowly upon the 1 Ohm resistor part of the question without widening your scope, seeing the larger picture. (I wouldn't know, of course, but you didn't write more.) That motivated me to *finish the thought* so to speak. Thanks for the kind words!!

Comment: @JohnD I did consider writing a comment to your answer, instead, but I couldn't find a way to write it that didn't make an assumption about what you perceived when writing and I didn't want to make any assumptions about your thinking. So I wrote a note to the OP and then after some moments decided to follow through with an answer, right afterwards.

Comment: I was busy at work, so really just answered the minimum about why the resistor was where it was, assuming that the lab instructions for the assignment would lead the OP through the rest of it, but your answer is much more complete and useful!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a current shunt to measure the current in the diode via the "Kanal2_Y" test point.

You would then have 1 V/A of current in the diode at the test point, because the 1 ohm resistor is referenced to ground.